# Eclipse crashed

Tags: java, eclipse

I have Windows 7 64 bit OS, I was just using Eclipse Helios, before I restart my pc, after the restart I am not able to use eclipse anymore. when I click on the eclipse icon, it opens but while loading it just stuck there, and when I click on it, I get the following message: JAVA (TM) Platform SE is not responding.

So, does anyone know what should I do?

Comment: you need to install a proper version of JAVA SDK check out eclipse compatiblity with x64bit . I think there is no eclipse x64 , so you need to install only JAVA SDK x86 and remove the x64 version

Comment: what did you change before that restart?

Comment: Did you apply any changes to the OS, e.g. Java Upgrade?

Comment: I didnt change anything, it was working perfectly.

Comment: A **lot** could be said about operating systems on which you can install Java without needing to have the admin password and which won't pollute other user accounts.  I **did** manage to get similar issues on Linux and after getting stuck for a bit too long I did: *a)* save all my files (they're saved regularly anyway) and then *b)* delete all trace of the user account and *c)* re-create the user account and re-install Java + my IDE + all the rest.  Pretty extreme, but on a system where *you* decide who's the boss, it's pretty failsafe.  It's the *b)* part which is problematic with Windows.

Answer (score 6):

Nima,
Are you on a 64 bit version of the JDK and 64 bit version of Helios? .
If not try having both on 64 bit, so that you can leverage your OS.
Also, edit your `eclipse.ini` file to launch it pointing to a specific vm.
eg :

```
-vm
myjdk/1.6.0_22/bin/javaw.exe
```

[SOLVED] Issue resolved with deleting the .snap file from  `yourworkspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources`

Explanation for the snap file :
While Eclipse is running, information about what has changed in the 
workspace is incrementally logged into various "snapshot" files 
(including .snap). On normal Eclipse shutdown, the complete workspace 
state is saved and the .snap files are deleted. When Eclipse crashes, 
the snapshot files are used during the next startup to recover from the 
crash.

So, it appears that some error is occuring that is causing Eclipse to 
crash. Then, there is an error recovering from the crash on the next 
startup. These are quite possibly unrelated problems, but by manually 
deleting the snapshot file you are tricking Eclipse into thinking that a 
crash did not occur, so the crash recovering routines do not run.

from http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/mv/msg/39563/129039/#msg_129039

Comment: I was using the same version of eclipse for about a month now, it was working just fine, I I was working with a VM file that I had within my eclipse, i was trying to get a webpage at my local host, I started tomcat and then in eclipse build ant, but I could get webpage at my local host, so I restart my pc, now when I run tomcat and when I go to my local host I can see the web page, but I cant open eclipse, I dont want to isntall it again because then I have to import so many things that would take me 3 hours or more to do. this is exactly what happend to me!!

Comment: You can try using `eclipse -clean` to try launching up again. Also try deleting the .snap file in `yourworkspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources`

Comment: There is an eclipse bug filed under the same exit code. : https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=319517. Are you on 6u21 jdk ?

Comment: i have this version 1.6.0_26.

Comment: I am not sure how to fix the bug.

Comment: Thank you its working now, I removed .snap file in myworkspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources, and then I restart eclipse, and it worked. I am not sure why after removing the .snap it started working again. what is in the .snap file??

Comment: Added explanation on the answer.

Comment: `find /home/me/ -size +9999999 -name \*.snap | xargs ls -ashd`  (I'm on Linux, but that would work on Cygwin, or port the idea to other command shell.)

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall eclipse and/or Java Runtime Environment. You can install either 32/64 bit version, but if you run eclipse 32 bit you need 32 bit JRE, with eclipse 64 bit, 64 bit JRE is required.